# Interpolation with gaps in domain

Tags: python, interpolation

I have experimental results for a scalar field over a plane.

The data points are taken over a 2D grid of (x, y) coordinates in the plane, but [there is a ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAKUQ.jpg) of (x, y) points in the plane where no data is taken, in some sense because the field isn't defined there.

How can i perform an interpolation over the 2D grid that takes into account this large lack of data points, and doesn't try to interpolate inside the torus?

Preferably I'd like to use one of the interpolators in the Python Scipy package.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to search for a solution before asking this question? If not, do so! If you did, mention why all the other solutions available do not help you.